# Draw a thermodynamic cycle with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a thermodynamic cycle like the one depicted in the attachment. Is there any package to do that? like something where a schematic for a turbine, compressor, heat-exchanger is predefined and one can load those schematics several times without repeating the details of drawing.

[image: cycle]

Comment: upload your code as MWE please

Comment: There is no code within my post. I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) To draw things with LaTeX, you can look at the [TikZ package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). You can then define the elements you need and combine them in a drawing. If you have a technical question about a code you have tried to write and does not work, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can help you to find a solution.

Comment: So far no one has created shapes for heat exchangers, turbines or compressors, but they really aren't that difficult.  If you plan to use them a lot, you can creates shapes, use pics or scopes.

Comment: For compressor and turbine there is the `shape=trapezium` (see pag.788 of [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) ver. 3.1.5b)

Comment: Thanks. That makes much easier the work than calculating precisely the lines for them. Thanks to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

My welcome to the TeX.SE. I drawing done with Mathcha: https://www.mathcha.io/editor.  with a bit bit of patience.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Flowchart: Manual Input [id:dp6138542499165982] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 190; blue, 234 }  ,fill opacity=0.3 ] (159.5,166.13) -- (73.5,156) -- (73.5,210) -- (159.5,210) -- cycle ;
%Flowchart: Manual Input [id:dp9875254540266645] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 190; blue, 234 }  ,fill opacity=0.3 ] (301.5,165.13) -- (385.5,155) -- (385.5,209) -- (301.5,209) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6337086211860903] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (302,189) -- (162.5,189.98) ;
\draw [shift={(159.5,190)}, rotate = 359.6] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da08999220916358364] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (386,188) -- (456.5,187.36) ;
\draw [shift={(459.5,187.33)}, rotate = 539.48] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6880698331583912] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (385.5,155) -- (385.02,92.33) ;
\draw [shift={(385,89.33)}, rotate = 449.56] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp24395445761741463] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 190; blue, 234 }  ,fill opacity=0.3 ] (335,49.33) -- (435.5,49.33) -- (435.5,90.19) -- (335,90.19) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp9853677636097984] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 190; blue, 234 }  ,fill opacity=0.3 ] (221.5,11) -- (283.5,11) -- (283.5,110) -- (221.5,110) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5425643556685251] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (186.75,61.17) -- (218.5,61.32) ;
\draw [shift={(221.5,61.33)}, rotate = 180.27] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da46197020884252704] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (221.75,99.83) -- (189.83,99.99) ;
\draw [shift={(186.83,100)}, rotate = 359.73] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Bend Up Arrow [id:dp38204157262003235] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (283.5,100) -- (301.73,100) -- (301.73,159.71) -- (299.29,159.71) -- (301.73,165.13) -- (304.17,159.71) -- (301.73,159.71) -- (301.73,100) -- (283.5,100) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp008616932216755302] 
\draw   (221.75,99.83) -- (232.87,99.83) -- (235.34,94.67) -- (240.28,105) -- (245.22,94.67) -- (250.16,105) -- (255.1,94.67) -- (260.03,105) -- (264.98,94.67) -- (269.92,105) -- (272.39,99.83) -- (283.5,99.83) ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp016982131407901058] 
\draw   (221.5,61.33) -- (232.62,61.33) -- (235.09,56.17) -- (240.03,66.5) -- (244.97,56.17) -- (249.91,66.5) -- (254.85,56.17) -- (259.78,66.5) -- (264.73,56.17) -- (269.67,66.5) -- (272.14,61.33) -- (283.25,61.33) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da503987886834304] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (334.83,61) -- (286.25,61.31) ;
\draw [shift={(283.25,61.33)}, rotate = 359.63] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7485401115489523] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 190; blue, 234 }  ,fill opacity=0.3 ] (124.5,9) -- (186.5,9) -- (186.5,108) -- (124.5,108) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp9535132579966799] 
\draw   (125,61.17) -- (136.12,61.17) -- (138.59,56) -- (143.53,66.33) -- (148.47,56) -- (153.41,66.33) -- (158.35,56) -- (163.29,66.33) -- (168.23,56) -- (173.17,66.33) -- (175.64,61.17) -- (186.75,61.17) ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp8757348861554459] 
\draw   (125.08,100) -- (136.2,100) -- (138.67,94.83) -- (143.61,105.17) -- (148.55,94.83) -- (153.49,105.17) -- (158.43,94.83) -- (163.37,105.17) -- (168.31,94.83) -- (173.25,105.17) -- (175.72,100) -- (186.83,100) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7093197672751996] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (125,61.17) -- (64.83,61.33) ;
\draw [shift={(61.83,61.33)}, rotate = 359.85] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8489122642916058] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (74,275.67) -- (73.52,213) ;
\draw [shift={(73.5,210)}, rotate = 449.56] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Bend Up Arrow [id:dp5089615847460833] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (351.83,21.33) -- (385.79,21.33) -- (385.79,40.37) -- (382.75,40.37) -- (385.79,47.13) -- (388.83,40.37) -- (385.79,40.37) -- (385.79,21.33) -- (351.83,21.33) -- cycle ;
%Bend Up Arrow [id:dp3803083804588667] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (73.5,156) -- (73.61,99.9) -- (116.87,99.98) -- (116.87,103.8) -- (123.66,99.99) -- (116.88,96.16) -- (116.87,99.98) -- (73.61,99.9) -- (73.5,156) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (74,181) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Compressor};
% Text Node
\draw (318,179) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Turbine};
% Text Node
\draw (345,47) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{57.151892pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
Combustion\\chamber
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (226.5,14) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{35.3175pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\tiny Ceramic: Heat \\ Exchanger}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (131.5,15) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{33.6175pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\tiny Metallic: Heat \\ Exchanger}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (318,12.33) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Fuel};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply

Comment: @user790082 You're welcome. :-) Best regards.